# Let $f(x)$ be a degree $r$ polynomial where $f(0)=p$. Show that $f(kp)$ is divisible by $p$

Tags: real-analysis

I am currently taking Real Analysis and am trying to work on the following problem:

> You may assume that a polynomial of degree $r$ has at most $r$ roots. Suppose that $$f(x)=\sum_{i=0}^r a_ix^i \quad a_i \in \mathbb{Z} $$
>   and that $f(0)=p$. Show that for every integer $k$, $f(kp)$ is divisible by $p$.

I'm not too sure how to go about solving this. I know that

$$f(0) = p \Rightarrow \sum_{i=0}^r a_i = p$$ and that

$$f(kp) = \sum_{i=0}^r a_i (kp)^i = \sum_{i=0}^r a_i k^i p^i$$

and that I seek to show that $f(x) = p\cdot g(x)$ for some other polynomial $g(x)$.

Any suggestions or hints would be appreciated.

Comment: This is wrong: $f(0) = p \implies \sum_{i=0}^r a_i = p$. What you need is: $f(0) = p \implies a_0 = p$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $f(0)=p$, then $a_0=p$ so that $f(kp)=\sum_{i=1}^r a_i(kp)^i+p$ which is clearly divisible by $p$.

Comment: How do you conclude that $f(0) = p$ implies $a_0 = p$?

Comment: Because $a_0=f(0)$.

Comment: How could I show that $f(kp)=p$ with what we have just established?

Comment: We have $f(kp)=\sum_{i=1}^r a_i(kp)^i+p$ so if you want $f(kp)=p$ for any $k$, then either $p=0$ or $a_1=\cdots=a_r=0$. So unless you have either of these, $f(kp)=p$ $\forall k$ is untrue in general.

Comment: Weird, the homework must be wrong then? I'll email the prof tonight and ask about it.

Comment: The homework asks that you show $f(kp)$ is divisible by $p$. It doesn't ask you to show that $f(kp)=p$, does it?

Comment: Part (b) asks to prove that using part (a)

Comment: Perhaps you can create another question to deal with (b). Remember to type out all given info in full. Good luck.